# using BNLearn from R in Python

Tags: python, r, rpy2, bnlearn

I am trying to pull R libraries into python so I can use them for data processing. The library in question is `BNLearn`. Using `rpy2`, I am able to pull `BNLearn` into python. However whenever I try to input a list into `BNlearn`, I receive the following error.

```py
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import ListVector, StrVector

BNLearn = importr("bnlearn")

SList = ['a','b','c','d','e']

res = StrVector(SList)

BNLearn.empty_graph(res)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py", line 345, in __call__
    return method()

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/vectors.py", line 683, in _repr_html_
    elements.append(e._repr_html_())

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/vectors.py", line 683, in _repr_html_
    elements.append(e._repr_html_())

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/vectors.py", line 690, in _repr_html_
    names.extend(self.names)

> TypeError: 'rpy2.rinterface.RNULLType' object is not iterable
```

I tried googling the error but not many posts talk about it. It claims the object is not iterable but if I use a basic python string, I receive the following

```py
BNLearn.empty_graph(SList)
```

> RRuntimeError: Error in check.nodes(nodes) : 
>     nodes must be a vector of character strings, the labels of the nodes.

`StrVector` was used to solve this error in the code above.

Comment: The traceback that is normally shown by Python when the `TypeError` occurs would be helpful.

Comment: I added in the traceback for the error

Comment: At first sight this is an issue (bug) in rpy2's rendering of that object. `mygraph = BNLearn.empty_graph(res)` would likely work without error. Can you open an issue in the rpy2 issue tracker on bitbucket ? Thanks.

Comment: stumbled on https://github.com/cs224/pybnl the other day. untested but perhaps useful.